# Solving Trig Equation $\cos(2x)=-\sin(2x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Proceeding as follows:

$$\cos(2x)=-\sin(2x)\Rightarrow 
\cos \left(2x\right)=-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-2x\right)$$

How to proceed further? Can I remove the $cos$ from both sides and proceed or no?

Comment: Alternatively: $\tan 2x = -1$, thus $2x = ... + k...$ for integer $k$

Comment: $\cos 2x = -\sin 2x = -\cos(\pi/2 - 2x) = \cos (\pi -(\pi/2-2x)) = \cos(\pi/2 +2x)$ which gives $2x = \pm(\pi/2+2x) + 2k\pi.$

Answer (score 2):

If $\cos(2x)=0$, then $-sin(2x)\neq 0$ (since $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$), so no solutions with $\cos(2x)=0$.

Hence, for any solution, $\cos(2x)\neq 0$, so can divide by $\cos(2x)$ without losing solutions.

This gives $1=-\frac{\sin(2x)}{\cos(2x)}=-\tan(2x)=\tan(-2x)$ since $\tan$ is odd.

Hence $-2x=\frac{\pi}{4}+z\pi$, so $x=-\frac{\pi}{8}+z\frac{\pi}{2}, z\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}=-1$ is definitely a better way.

Alternatively, 
$$\cos2x=-\sin2x=\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2+2x\right)$$

If $\cos A=\cos B,A=2n\pi\pm B$ where $n$ is any integer

OR,

$$\sin2x=-\cos2x=-\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2-2x\right)$$

$$\sin2x=\sin\left(2x-\dfrac\pi2\right)$$

Now $\sin C=\sin D\implies C=m\pi+(-1)^m D$ where  $m$ is any integer

Answer (score 1):

hint:

$cos(2x)+sin(2x)=0$

$cos(2x)+cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-2x)=0$; now writing sum into product

$2cos(\frac{\pi}{4})cos(\frac{\pi}{4}-2x)=0$;hence

general solution  :$x=(-\frac{n\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{8})$

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: no.

If $\cos a = \cos b$ it doesn't follow that $a = b$. It only follows that $$a = b + 2k\pi \quad\text{ if } \cos a=\cos b \neq 0$$ and $$a = b + k\pi \quad\text{ if } \cos a = \cos b = 0$$ The easiest way to see that might be to look at a graph of $y = \cos x$.

If $\cos a = -\cos b$ then $\cos a = \cos(b + \pi)$ and now you can use the results above.

---

Thus in your case, $\cos 2x = -\cos (\pi/2 - 2x)$ implies that

$$\cos 2x = \cos(3\pi/2 - 2x)$$
and thus

$$2x = 3\pi/2 - 2x + 2k\pi$$
(as it is not the case that both terms are non-zero. Why?)

Hence $4x = 3\pi/2 + 2k\pi$ or finally

$$\boxed{x = \frac{3\pi}{8} + k\frac\pi 2 \quad\text{ for integer } k}$$

For instance: for $k = 0$, $2x = 3\pi/4$ and $\cos 2x = -1/\sqrt 2 = -\sin 2x$.

---

Alternatively, $\displaystyle\frac{\sin 2x}{\cos 2x} = - 1$ or $\tan 2x = -1$. Thus

$$2x = -\frac \pi 4 + k\pi \quad\text{ for integer } k$$

or

$$\boxed{x = -\frac \pi 8 + k\frac\pi 2 \quad\text{ for integer } k}$$

This is the same as the answer above with the integer $k$ "shifted" by $1$.